# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error()

Tags: wordpress

I have built a website with wordpress which has recently stopped working. I am unable to login using he Wp-Admin page. When I login I get the following error, listed in the code below.

I wondered whether it might have been the rev slider causing problems. I have updated the base class admin.php file to change `private static $arrMetaBoxes = '';` to `private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();`. This unfortunately has not worked.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error() in /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(127): UniteDBRev->checkForErrors('fetch') #1 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_params.class.php(42): UniteDBRev->fetch('wp_xiht_revslid...') #2 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_operations.class.php(1072): RevSliderParams->getFieldFromDB('general') #3 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_front.php(30): RevOperations::getGeneralSettingsValues() #4 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): RevSliderFront->onAddScripts('') #5 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-includes/script-loader.php(1049): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #6 /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-includes/plugin.php(525): wp in /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php on line 29

Warning: Parameter 1 to W3_Plugin_TotalCache::ob_callback() expected to be a reference, value given in /home3/epicccon/public_html/sophia/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3570
```

Comment: try deactivate w3 total cache plugin (rename the folder using ftp) and try changing into default theme

Answer (score 5):

You will need to update the source code of revolution slider plugin.
**Edit wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php**
Find ***checkForErrors*** function and replace below piece of code

```
if(mysql_error()){
```

with

```
if($this->wpdb->last_error){
```

Comment: Thanks, although that fixes the one line an additional change is also required in base_admin.class.php. Line 23 needs replacing with `private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no other reason that PHP 7.0+ stopped support mysql_* function, including mysql_connect(), mysql_error(),... Maybe your hosting provider upgrading to PHP 7.x without your attention.

Please consider upgrade your code base to the newest version: WordPress, themes, plugins. Another *bad* option is downgrade to PHP 5.x as previous.

Ask your hosting provider for their advise.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by Ejaz, editing the line of code in wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php should work.

another solution is to try the suggestion in the php documentation and replacing that same line of code:

```
if(mysql_error()){
```

with the code:

```
if($mysqli -> error){
```

see [php mysql_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

also don't forget to change the line of code in base_admin.class.php

```
private static $arrMetaBoxes = '';
```

to

```
private static $arrMetaBoxes = [];
```